# Create a ListView in MFC without having dialogs

Tags: c++, listview, mfc

I am trying to create a ListView in MFC C++ in my Child window. I have just finished reading [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608/Using-the-List-Control). I recommend it to anyone who wants to create the control in a dialog or that has created it already and tries to learn more about it.

Here comes my question! **I have to create the `ListView` control at `::OnCreate()` of my ChildWindow.** How can I do this?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
int CChildFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CMDIChildWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CListCtrl *CarsListView = new CListCtrl();
    CarsListView->SetView(LVS_REPORT);
    CarsListView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    return 0;
}
```

(code that is obviously not working...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no Need to use new to create a list view object.
2. Creating the object doesn't create the window. You Need to call CListView::Create

Maybe you should read a MFC tutorial...